# tags: security vs. anti-cheat

Tags: discussion, tags

I've added [security](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) to two questions tagged [anti-cheat](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-cheat), then I realized there is no clear question which addresses "anti-cheat" without being also more in general related to "security".

I'd like us to either produce some guidelines about when to use these tags, or to remove [anti-cheat](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-cheat) altogether if it is a duplicate or a subset of [security](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security).

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion [anti-cheat](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-cheat) is a subset of [security](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) - in the same way that, say, [xna](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xna) is a subset of [game-development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-development). Using hyperbole: if we removed subset tags we would ultimately land up with exactly one tag ([game-development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-development)). Security could further be broken down into things such as: authentication, in-game-purchases, encryption, privacy and, yes, anti-cheat - all of these help an answerer discriminate between questions where her expertise might lie. So I would say: update the wiki of [security](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) to include other tags like [anti-cheat](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-cheat).

Comment: +1 Anticheat is a specific topic worth having a tag for, and you provided an undefeatable case for subset tags. c(:

Comment: I agree. Every anti-cheat tagged question is security related, but not every security tagged question is anti-cheat related!