# Should there be a difference between 'state' tags and 'fsm' tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Are there any questions that could pertain specifically to a state that are not inherent in an overall fsm (finite state machine)? It seems like any 'state' tag falls under the fsm umbrella because without knowing the context under which the state would be operating is detrimental to any possible information about the state itself.

There was a similar question asked here: [tags: security vs. anti-cheat](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/751/tags-security-vs-anti-cheat)

I guess I'm wondering if questions tagged with 'state' or 'states' are at all different from questions tagged 'fsm' (even though they are clearly a subset). A better way to ask this is: "Are there tags that could be tagged as 'fsm' that would not be able to be tagged as 'state' or 'states' (which are synonyms)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the fact that at least **N** people use the term "state" and actually implement a FSM in their applications, without knowing what a FSM actually is, makes the "state" tag useful.

In most game programming tutorials (that I've seen anyway) there's a lot of talk on states, but very little on finite state machines. A considerable amount of questions may come from readers of such tutorials.

What I mean is, a user who is able to tell that FSM includes state is also able to notice the redundancy (if it exists) of the state tag. A user who is not able to do so, however, will use the state tag and that's perfectly fine from my point of view. A question that asks about FSM related stuff and has the tags `<C++> <DirectX> <State(s)>` is a lot better than an equivalent tagged as `<C++> <DirectX>`