# Should we do something with tags 'fsm' and 'state'?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have these two tags:

- [state](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/state): 120 questions, one synonym ([states](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/states)), a description *"Generally used in correlation with a state machine."*
- [fsm](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fsm): 49 questions, a description *"Finite State Machines model game flow, AI behaviour, or other processes using a set of discrete states and transitions between them. "*

And there are 22 questions that have both.

Since they're closely related should we do something about them?

There has been some [discussion in the past](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1085/40264), with the conclusion *"let's leave them separated, because users don't know the relationship between those"*, but I feel this should be revised.

Answer (score 3):

From the linked discussion, and from the numbers of tags attributions, users seem more inclined to use the tag `state`. However, as a guideline question, can one be expert in `state`, or are they expert in `finite-state-machines`?

I think users would be more experts in `finite-state-machines`. However, as previously stated, `fsm` is not intuitively found by users.

So I suggest we make `state` a synonym of `fsm`, as `fsm` has a more complete tag-wiki, and *then* rename `fsm` to `state-machine`.

Comment: This seems reasonable to me.

Comment: I think renaming the fsm tag to state-machine is particularly useful, so that it comes up as a suggestion when a user starts typing "state." I also find my colleagues more commonly call these "state machines" in practice, with the "finite" basically assumed (I certainly haven't yet made a game system with a truly unbounded collection of states...) ;)